# Javascript Form serialize issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a form where we enter text , which is saved using ajax

```
<form id='frm'>
<input type='textbox' id='content' name='content'>
</form>
```

javascript function to save the content using ajax

```
function saveValues()
{
 var param = "&"+ Form.serialize("frm");
try {
var request = new Ajax.Request('detail.php',
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters: params,
            onSuccess: function(transport)
            {
                        // update values
                    }

}
catch(err) { alert(err.description);}
}
```

If the text is normal it works, it text contain characters like ☐ HTML -> "&# 9744;"
the form serialize step gives a error, is there a way to escape the symbols before we serialize.

Comment: which javascript framework are you using? for prototype it should be $('frm').serialize() and for jquery, it should be $('#frm').serialize();

Comment: We don't even know what `Form.serialize` looks like. We can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: What error do u get @Naveen Kumar

Comment: It goes into the catch block, the value doesnt have space, just for display the characters i have given space, @nur prototype

Comment: you should be fine just by adding name atrribute in form tag definition like: <form id="frm" name="frm">

Comment: @NaveenKumar aren't you supposed to pass in the DOM element instance instead of its `id`?

Comment: @nur, i think its not a problem with form name , but the & in param and the & in the symbol are HTML are creating the problem, as without that symbol, i can save

Comment: in that case, i think you need to convert special character like "&" to corresponding entity character/number before serializing. javascript function "encodeURIComponent" can do that. i don't think built-in serialize function is able to take care of this case. so you need to write your own serialize function.